# What is negative effects of setting max.poll.interval.ms larger than request.timeout.ms in Kafka consumer configs

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

According to Kafka documentation;

> The new Java Consumer now supports heartbeating from a background
>   thread. There is a new configuration max.poll.interval.ms which
>   controls the maximum time between poll invocations before the consumer
>   will proactively leave the group (5 minutes by default). The value of
>   the configuration request.timeout.ms must always be larger than
>   max.poll.interval.ms because this is the maximum time that a JoinGroup
>   request can block on the server while the consumer is rebalancing, so
>   we have changed its default value to just above 5 minutes.

But I couldn't understand the possible results of making max.poll.interval.ms larger than request.timeout.ms.

Can anybody explain this part of document:

> because this is the maximum time that a JoinGroup request can block on
>   the server while the consumer is rebalancing

Now I'am using these consumer parameters in my project:

```
kafka.consumer.session.timeout.ms=30000
kafka.consumer.heartbeat.interval.ms=10000
kafka.consumer.request.timeout.ms=31000
kafka.consumer.max.poll.interval.ms=259200000
kafka.consumer.max.partition.fetch.bytes=10242880
```

What would be the negative effects of these usage?

Note: My kafka-clients version is 1.1.0

### UPDATE

From Kafka version 2.0.0 this rule is not valid anymore. From Kafka docs Notable changes in 2.0.0:

> Also as part of KIP-266, the default value of request.timeout.ms has
>   been changed to 30 seconds. The previous value was a little higher
>   than 5 minutes to account for maximum time that a rebalance would
>   take. **Now we treat the JoinGroup request in the rebalance as a special
>   case and use a value derived from max.poll.interval.ms for the request
>   timeout.** All other request types use the timeout defined by
>   request.timeout.ms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`request.timeout.ms` specifies how long the consumer will wait for a response from the broker.

`max.poll.interval.ms` is used in a couple of use cases. It first specifies how often the consumer was to intereact with brokers (to confirm it's alive) but it's also used when the consumer joins a group. In this case, it indicates how long the broker can take to respond to the join group request.

So if `max.poll.interval.ms` is larger than `request.timeout.ms`, you see that the broker may take longer to respond than the consumer will wait. So the consumer could timeout requests.

In many cases, the defaults values for these 2 configurations are relatively good. Instead of overriding them to the large values I see in your question, you should first start by clearly identify how you want to change the default behaviour.

Comment: Thx for reply. Actually the reason I change default parameter values is that I want the message that cannot be processed to be stucked in a loop (to avoid skipping messages) and also my thread should stay in the group. (I also set heartbeat parameter to a smaller value to realize failure) Is it okay to use max.poll.interval.ms parameter that much for that reason ?