# Can Kafka be asked to wait less than max.poll.interval.ms during a JoinGroup?

Tags: apache-kafka

**Background:** I have an application, running in Kubernetes, which uses Kafka as a centralised message bus. The Kafka clients in my application can be quite slow. The maximum time the Kafka broker will wait between subsequent poll() calls, before kicking a member out of a group and rebalancing, is controlled by `max.poll.interval.ms`.

For most of the workers in this application, I can set `max.poll.interval.ms` to something of the order of a few minutes. However, for workers in slower classes, I need to set it to be a few hours.

When everything is working normally, this doesn't cause an issue. However, in case of network disruption or intermittent crashes, I have noticed that the workers with very large maximum poll intervals can get "stuck" in rebalance. If I look on the broker when this happens, and execute something like

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group my-group --describe --members
```

then I see that the broker is waiting for a bunch of workers which just don't exist any longer (I am sure that this is the case, because I set the `group.instance.id` to the Kubernetes pod hostname, so I can verify that the stuck group members really are gone).

Via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54822434/what-is-negative-effects-of-setting-max-poll-interval-ms-larger-than-request-tim), I see that KIP-266 says that "*The JoinGroup API will be treated as a special case and its timeout will be set to a value derived from max.poll.interval.ms.*" What I guess is happening, then, is that my workers are sending a JoinGroup just before being disconnected from the broker somehow, and this is causing the broker to wait the full `max.poll.interval.ms` before marking them as dead and allowing the new workers to be rebalanced.

When this happens, it seems that I have to take down the Kafka brokers and bring them back up in order to clear out the dead members... or else all of the processing gets stuck for a few hours whilst the broker waits the full timeout. These are both bad solutions and I'm not happy with either.

**My question is:** Is there a setting that I can adjust to encourage Kafka to wait less than `max.poll.interval.ms` before giving up on a JoinGroup request? If this means that there's a little churn in rebalancing after a network interruption, as very slow consumers rejoin the group late, then I'm fine with that. If there is no such mechanism, how should I refactor my system to avoid the issues I'm seeing?

I'm running Confluent Kafka `confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.1`, which seems to be Kafka 2.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

In Kafka when rebalance starts in a consumer group all the consumers in this consumer group is revoked and Kafka waits all alive consumers (consumers that send heartbeat) to poll() (calling poll for a revoked consumer means JoinGroupRequest). The important thing is that:

```
rebalance timeout = max.poll.interval.ms
```

and this **cannot be changed**. Actually it is reasonable, because Kafka waits alive consumers to complete its job and re-join to the group. So rebalance is completed when all alive consumers send joinGroupRequests or rebalance timeout happens.

During rebalance, because all the consumers in consumer group are revoked, consume operation is stopped for this consumer group. So as a good practice, long running processes should be avoided.

As a result:

**long running processes lead -> long max.poll.interval.ms time leads -> long rebalance time**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you're right, but I disagree that this is a reasonable choice on the part of the Kafka developers. I don't understand why Kafka can't be configured to complete the initial rebalance after some short timeout and then, if there are other consumers which join later, rebalance again.

Comment: @monoi Actually I think in the latest releases the thing that you mention has already developed. (I haven't tested it yet but I guess it can satisfy your expectations about rebalance). You can check [this](https://www.confluent.io/blog/incremental-cooperative-rebalancing-in-kafka/) and [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-415%3A+Incremental+Cooperative+Rebalancing+in+Kafka+Connect)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved this (and it seems there might not be a solution), but I might have found a way to improve things a little: set `group.instance.id` to the Kubernetes hostname, and also use StatefulSets in Kubernetes, so that the hostname for a particular worker is stable. This way, when a worker crashes and rejoins, hopefully Kafka is able to recognize it as the *same* worker, instead of hanging around waiting for a ghost.

Answer (score 0):

My ultimate solution here was to move to Apache Pulsar.

Pulsar allows messages to be ack'd individually, which solves the problem.